# Open link in a new webpage from HTML in apps script

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script

I have an Google Apps Script web app, which will display html page to get project name. I already have a spreadsheet template which has to be copied and renamed with the project name that's submitted in the html form. This is working fine. I get a spreadsheet created with the project name entered in html page in my drive.

What I need is to open the newly created spreadsheet in a new tab after submitting the form in html.

Code.gs

```
    function doGet(request) {
  return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('Index').evaluate();
}

/* @Include JavaScript and CSS Files */
function include(filename) {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile(filename)
      .getContent();
}

/* @Process Form */
function processForm(formObject) 
{

    
  var destination = DriveApp.getFolderById('Id')
  var ss= DriveApp.getFileById('Id').makeCopy(formObject.project_name, destination)
  
  var url= ss.getUrl()
  
 var html2 = "<script>window.open('" + url + "');google.script.host.close();</script>";
 var userInterface = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(html2);
 userInterface.setTitle('Creating New Estimate')
 return userInterface
 
}
```

Index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <base target="_top">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
      <?!= include('JavaScript'); ?>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-6">
                    <form id="myForm" onsubmit="handleFormSubmit(this)">
                        <p class="h4 mb-4 text-left">Creating a New Estimate</p>

                        <div class="form-row">
                            <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                                <label for="project_name">Please enter the Project Name</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="project_name" name="project_name" placeholder="Project Name" required>
                            </div>
                           
                        </div>
              
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Submit</button>
                        
                              <p><a href="webpage link">Click Here</a>  to go back to the proposal management site.</p>
                              
                    </form>
                    <div id="output"></div>
                </div>
            </div>      
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

JavaScript.html

```
    <script>
  // Prevent forms from submitting.
  function preventFormSubmit() {
    var forms = document.querySelectorAll('form');
    for (var i = 0; i < forms.length; i++) {
      forms[i].addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      });
    }
  }
  window.addEventListener('load', preventFormSubmit);    
      
      
  function handleFormSubmit(formObject) {

    google.script.run.processForm(formObject);
    document.getElementById("myForm").reset();
   
 }
  
</script>
```

Comment: See [mcve]. **Describe the problem. "It doesn't work" isn't descriptive enough to help people understand your problem. Instead, tell other readers what the expected behavior should be. Tell other readers what the exact wording of the error message is, and which line of code is producing it. Use a brief but descriptive summary of your problem as the title of your question**

Comment: You didn't read the question fully. Read the 2nd paragraph to know what the expected behaviour is. There is no error in the code. Just copy paste the code and replace the ID with original values, it's going to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using this approach:

```
google.script.run
.withSuccessHandler(function(){
  //Go back and access the spreadsheet here
})
.processForm(formObject);
```

Comment: Thanks for the response Cooper. I tried this, but didn't work. If I have conveyed the use case clearly. The script creates a file in my drive, but I want to open the newly created spreadsheet in a new tab.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know this. But this piece of code works. It actually opens the sheet.

https://script.google.com/d/14BzFQ42KjdvtcHrJnvgPAOAcw1EyIirdgRfT-YjRGtjFF0nIsO6H0WwF/edit?usp=sharing

Thanks again for responding Cooper.

Answer (score 0):

Get the url of the spreadsheet
use the url in the below function to open it in another tab in the same browser window

```
//
//
function openUrl( url ){
  var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput('<html><script>'
  +'window.close = function(){window.setTimeout(function(){google.script.host.close()},9)};'
  +'var a = document.createElement("a"); a.href="'+url+'"; a.target="_blank";'
  +'if(document.createEvent){'
  +'  var event=document.createEvent("MouseEvents");'
  +'  if(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf("firefox")>-1){window.document.body.append(a)}'                          
  +'  event.initEvent("click",true,true); a.dispatchEvent(event);'
  +'}else{ a.click() }'
  +'close();'
  +'</script>'
  // Offer URL as clickable link in case above code fails.
  +'<body style="word-break:break-word;font-family:sans-serif;">Failed to open automatically. <a href="'+url+'" target="_blank" onclick="window.close()">Click here to proceed</a>.</body>'
  +'<script>google.script.host.setHeight(40);google.script.host.setWidth(410)</script>'
  +'</html>')
  .setWidth( 90 ).setHeight( 1 );
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog( html, "Opening ..." );
}
//
//
function open_help(){
 openUrl("https://docs.google.com/document/d/1zDY/edit");
}
//
//
```

Comment: Hi Arul, I can use the spreadsheet app's UI and open it new tab. But if  you look at my code, it actually uses html service. This piece of code works, but not the one that I mentioned in the question. Thanks

https://script.google.com/d/14BzFQ42KjdvtcHrJnvgPAOAcw1EyIirdgRfT-YjRGtjFF0nIsO6H0WwF/edit?usp=sharing